# Lazyload cutting off image height when dynamic height is turned on

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, lazy-loading

When I enable Lazyload on my image slideshow with the dynamic height enabled, it cuts off and only shows a fraction of the photo height, I have attached a screenshot, if the initial load you can view the images perfectly, please use the toggle arrows and you will be able to see what I mean.

I have been trying various fixes to no avail and as this was a html theme I purchased, unfortunately, the theme author has also not been able to help me, your help will be much appreciated.

The JS I have in my custom script file is:

```
     $(".property-carousel").owlCarousel({ 
         rtl: _rtl, items: 1, lazyLoad : true, 
         responsiveBaseWidth: ".property-slide", dots: false, 
         autoHeight: true, nav: true, navText: ["", ""], loop: true 
      });
```

[image: here is also a screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

I also had this problem, "lazyLoad" combined with "autoHeight" cut off some images because the lazy-loaded images' heights weren't taken into account by the owl carousel. For me, this works (modification of the answer from @baduga):

```
var myCarousel = $(".property-carousel").owlCarousel({ 
    lazyLoad : true, 
    autoHeight: true
});
myCarousel.on('loaded.owl.lazy', function(event) {
    myCarousel.trigger('refresh.owl.carousel');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try to add auto height on function

```
owlCarousel({
      items: 1,
      loop: true,
      autoHeight: true
    });
```

set auto height true

```
autoHeight: true
```

Comment: Hi Alfin, I have already set it to true, here is a copy what I have below in the custom.js, am I missing something within?      $(".property-carousel").owlCarousel({
                rtl: _rtl,
                items: 1,
                lazyLoad : true,
            responsiveBaseWidth: ".property-slide",
                        dots: false,
                        autoHeight: true,
                        nav: true,
                        navText: ["", ""],
                        loop: true
                    });

Comment: give the data-src-retina="image path" to the first two image

Answer (score 0):

You need to set lazyload true in OwlCarousel:

```
lazyLoad: true
```

[Go to the documentation for more](https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/demos/lazyLoad.html).

Comment: Hi Nathaniel, It has already been set, the lazy load is working, however the issue I am having is the images cutting off when it is enabled

Comment: None of the images are the same size in your sliders. Once they are, OwlCarousel knows how large to make the slider and it acts consistently. Try setting a min-height on each owl-item which you can adjust to be responsive with media queries.

Comment: I do understand the issue. What you need are all the images to be the same size, and then for owl carousel to know about those images. It's possible autoHeight doesn't work with lazyload, have you tried turning it off for a test?

Comment: After a lot of messing around, I found that updating to the latest version and having to then adapt it to fit the theme again, I managed to get this working again, many thanks for pointing me to the correct website which I downloaded the latest version from.

Comment: Oh great! Funny I had the same issue with the Owl Carousel plugin for wp. Updating the plugin fixed an issue I was having with it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution of the problem:

```
gallery.owlCarousel({
    margin:5,
    loop:false,
    autoHeight:true,
    items:1,
    nav: false,
    dots: false,
    lazyLoad:true
});
gallery.on('loaded.owl.lazy', function(event) {
    $(this).find('.owl-item.active img').one('load', function () {
        gallery.trigger('refresh.owl.carousel');
    });
});
```